# Spring Custom Security Expression - Error : Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor'

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm facing a problem after following this Baeldung tutorial to make custom security expression using spring security: [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression
I have the following error :

```
Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in defined in MethodSecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0, org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager, authenticationManagerBean]
```

MethodSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
      DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
            new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
      expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
      return expressionHandler;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't... That isn't recommended anymore. Just write a bean which has a method that returns `boolean` and call it from your `@PreAuthorize` like `@bean.yourmethod`. A lot easier and doesn't require fiddling with the Spring Security beans.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I've already have a boolean method: `@Override
 public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
 }` Is it a method like this one you were thinking about ? How can I call it from @PreAuthorize ? Thank you :)

Comment: That is an implementation of an interface. You can just write the method as you like. I already showed how to call it in my initial comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Here's my new method that return a boolean `@Component("authorizationVerification")
public class AuthorizationVerification {


 public boolean isAuthorized(String fonctionnalite) {}` and the annotation that can be placed above a method that needs to be restricted is ` @PreAuthorize("@authorizationVerification.isAuthorized('permission')")
` is that correct ? Thanks again for your responses :)